# How to print test output or log at the end of "Kitchen Converge"?

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, chef-solo, test-kitchen

We are compiling cucumber tests using Kitchen. We could able to run the test cases and everything is good. What we want is, printing the test report at the end of the Kitchen Converge.

Is it possible to run a chef recipe in debug mode.

We know "kitchen converge -l Debug" will print the whole output, but we don't want all the log. Just particular test report.

Answer (score 0):

You don't run the tests during converge unless you're still using the very old and deprecated minitest system. Tests run during the verify phase and display their output there.